# Using a nonce in a Custom Login Form

Tags: php, login, cookies

I am trying to create my own login form for WordPress using wp-login.php as a template.

In the form that is used to collect login information from the user (lines 680 through 703 of wp-login.php), there doesn't seem to be any implementation of a nonce.

I have been told by quite a few people that I should always be using a nonce when collecting information from forms - but there is not a single reference to a nonce in this entire file - despite their being four fairly critical forms.

So - what am I missing?

I know that the login form uses a testcookie and that you create a securecookie when reading through the POST information - but does that somehow solve the security issue?  Are there any good resources out there for understanding how secure cookies work in this instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> using wp-login.php as a template.

is not a correct way to do that.

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)

You'd better use the [wp_login_form()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) function in a custom template.

EDIT:

And if you want to add an option to reset password you could do this :

```
add_action( 'login_form_middle', 'add_lost_password_link' );
function add_lost_password_link() {
return '<a href="/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Lost Password?</a>';
}
```

[Source](http://trepmal.com/2011/04/06/add-the-lost-password-link-to-wp_login_form-output/)

Comment: but if I use wp_login_form(), how will I handle password resets?

Comment: I've edited code. Actually this won't be problematic ;)

Comment: but with your solution, it would then utilize the wp-login.php page, correct?  I am trying to avoid that because I want to make a page with different functionality -